# Transition from Location header to Content-Disposition header in order to get rid of browser warning

Tags: php, download, header

Until now I used Location header for downloading files from my website. It was giving in Chrome

*This file could be dangerous | Discard* message. (At least on Windows.)

I have the very same files hosted on many software websites and nowhere it gives such a warning. That is why I looked around for a solution.

On [Header Test](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php) I get this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK => 
Server => nginx
Date => Sun, 24 Apr 2016 10:24:19 GMT
Content-Type => application/zip
Content-Length => 10635840
Connection => close
Set-Cookie => lng=en; expires=Mon, 24-Apr-2017 10:24:19 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=www.vlastimilburian.cz
Accept-Ranges => bytes
Content-Disposition => attachment; filename="extreme_password_generator.zip"
Content-Language => cs
```

And after I set the headers in this download script

https://www.vlastimilburian.cz/download.php?pid=12&portable

I run the following:

```
$fn = fopen($product_object->get_file_name(), "r");
fpassthru($fn);
```

Which is completely different solution than using Location header. Yet so far no success.

Am I on the right track? Or what do I miss?

Comment: Are executables in the zip file? If so, you get the warning because of this. Otherwise submit the link for review to google. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1249981?hl=en

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Yes, they are, but as I said, those files are hosted on many sites and it gives no warning. http://download.cnet.com/Solid-Geometry-Portable/3001-2053_4-75860253.html?hlndr=1

Comment: @CharlotteDunois As compared to my from my site https://www.vlastimilburian.cz/download.php?pid=3&portable where the warning is

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6261569?p=ib_download_blocked&hl=en&rd=1 Submit the link for review to google, they can tell you more about this.